# python flask-Unable to upload file using POSTMAN of other computer in same network

Tags: python, flask, cross-domain, flask-sqlalchemy

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/uploads', methods=['POST','OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def upload_file():
file = request.files['image']
print file
# if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

    data={'message':'success'}
    return jsonify(data)
```

I m getting BAD request when i m trying to upload file from POSTMAN of other computer of same network but its working in my POSTMAN. I m unable to understand whats happening ? But i am access other routes through postman of other computer only file upload route is giving bad request. I have checked folder permissions too.

i have tried writing own decorator but still getting same error

I am able to upload file from my own postman but unable to do an upload from other computers postman which is on same network.

I think its cross domains issue but unable to understand

Comment: @AmiHollander i m able to upload files from my own computer i.e local host but unable to do from computers in same network

Comment: oh sorry, deleted my comment